# QGraphicsEllipseItem how to catch events

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I'm working on MAC OS X / Qt 5.3 widget application and I've run into a problem. I have `QGraphicsView` containing scene with movable `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, but I don't know how to catch the end of a move event.

What I'm trying to do is trigger a method every time the drag event of a point ends (and if that is not possible then when it moves), but I don't know where to start or what to do. I'd prefer not to make my own implementation of `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, but if it's the only option I'm probably going to need a hand with it.

The problem is also I don't know where to listen to these events, I have a class that inserts the points into the widget and generally serves as a code-behind for it and I'd like to do the catching there since the method is accessible from there and gets specific data from it. I'm completely at loss of what to do or how to do it.
I don't want complete code, but I'd appreciate an example, if you can (with placement specified).

Comment: Can't you use the `QGraphicsView::dropEvent` for that? Maybe you combine it with `QGraphicsView::itemAt` using the coordinates of the event to make sure you are interacting with the right object

Comment: A raw drag always starts with a mouse-press + mouse-move and ends with a mouse-release.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, both. I just don't know where to listen to these events or how. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SebastianLange commented, you need to handle the mouse events. There are two ways of doing this, based upon the same method.

A `QGraphicsItem` supports the following functions:

```
virtual void    mouseMoveEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event )
virtual void    mousePressEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event )
virtual void    mouseReleaseEvent ( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event )
```

The first method would be to inherit from `QGraphicsEllipseItem` and override the `mouseEvent`s, which would allow you to know when the item has been moved and a call in the `mouseReleaseEvent` signals that the move has ended.

If you don't want to inherit from `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, another method is to [install a scene event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#installSceneEventFilter)

This involves creating a separate object derived from `QGraphicsItem`, overloading the mouse events (as above) and then installing this object as the event filter for the `QGraphicsEllipseItem` object.

Personally, I'd recommend using the first method and inherit from `QGraphicsEllipseItem`.